# localhost took too long to respond. windows10 reactjs

Tags: reactjs, localhost

I was working on a new react project everything was good but now I cannot access my development server I tried running windows troubleshooter it shot me something

[image: Image of localhost took too long to respond]

[image: Windows Troubleshooter]

[image: My react app also compiled succesfully]

I do no what is the problem is I tried disabling antivirus and even allowing localhost in my antivirus(Quick heal).

```
The device or resource (localhost) is not set up to accept connections on port "3000".
```

Contact your network administrator Completed

The computer or device you are trying to reach is available, but it doesn’t support what you’re trying to do. This might be a configuration issue or a limitation of the device.

Things I tried to solve this

1. Disabled firewall and antivirus
2. Allowed my antivirus(Quick heal) to access the site
3. Restarting the computer and router

I think the problem is with windows.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be with Chrome browser. Which maybe does not allow you to go to insecure (HTTP) pages

Go to settings.

[image]

Then Security in Security and Privacy tab.

[image]

Toggle Always use secure connections

[image]